# Internal working of cts:register queries

Tags: marklogic

Can anyone please share an in depth concept of cts:register queries? What exactly happens when we register the query,how does it effect the expanded tree cache and will the register queries are going to be stored on e-nodes?

If the register ids are going to be stored on e-nodes then is there any possibility of having same id's that can be generated on the different enode hosts if we have the same cts:query constructors are being used?

Comment: Ken Tune provided some detail in a comment on the [cts:registered-query](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:registered-query) page.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the detail on the [cts:registered-query](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:registered-queryhttp://) page that Dave suggested, there is also a good review of how it works in the "Inside MarkLogic Server" e-Book [(Download it here)](http://cdn.marklogic.com/wp-content/uploads/resources/Inside-MarkLogic-Server.pdf?type=www&publisher=tile&utm_source=www.marklogic.com&utm_medium=frontpagecta&utm_campaign=imlsebook&iesrc=ctr) starting on page 77. Not sure if it has all the details you're looking for, but there is explanation for what's happening under the hood.

Comment: Is there any chance of retrieving the forest id and the data information that is extracted in expanded tree cache while posting the query request to the application server in marklogic? I have tried looking into Meteres database and using the xdmp:server-status api but no luck at this end to get the information

Comment: And can we get the status of all the old requests to read using any our marklogic apis.For eg : xdmp:request-status gives the information at that partiular instance i am running can i get the same information also after 5 mins like that. Does the request details store in some other database like meters as we have in marklogic?

Comment: I need a internal understanding of cts:registered queries, but i dont see that explanation in inside marklogic server ebook. And the registered queries run on the E-node I have found this information in some marklogic site.